# compiler error in building a simulator for GPGPU

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, ubuntu-10.04

When i am building a simulator by the make command in my command line, it worked correctly in beginning and finally it results the following

```
make -C ./libcuda/ depend
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sai/gpgpu-sim/v3.x/libcuda'
Makefile:140: Makefile.makedepend: No such file or directory
touch Makefile.makedepend
makedepend -fMakefile.makedepend -p../build/4000/release/libcuda/ cuda_runtime_api.cc 2> /dev/null
make[1]: `depend' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sai/gpgpu-sim/v3.x/libcuda'
make -C ./libcuda/
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sai/gpgpu-sim/v3.x/libcuda'
touch Makefile.makedepend
makedepend -fMakefile.makedepend -p../build/4000/release/libcuda/ cuda_runtime_api.cc 2> /dev/null
g++  -std=c++0x -O3 -g -Wall -Wno-unused-function -Wno-sign-compare -fPIC  -DCUDART_VERSION=4000 -I./ -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -c cuda_runtime_api.cc -o ../build/4000/release/libcuda/cuda_runtime_api.o
cuda_runtime_api.cc: In function ‘void extract_code_using_cuobjdump()’:
cuda_runtime_api.cc:1306: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int system(const char*)’,declared with attribute warn_unused_result
cuda_runtime_api.cc: In function ‘char* readfile(std::string)’:
cuda_runtime_api.cc:1408: warning: ignoring return value of ‘size_t fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
cuda_runtime_api.cc: In function ‘void** __cudaRegisterFatBinary(void*)’:
cuda_runtime_api.cc:1686: internal compiler error: **in gen_type_die_with_usage, at dwarf2out.c:14767
Please submit a full bug report,**
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[1]: *** [../build/4000/release/libcuda/cuda_runtime_api.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sai/gpgpu-sim/v3.x/libcuda'
make: *** [cudalib] Error 2
```

Is this a problem in gcc compiler, I use gcc 4.4 on my Ubuntu 10.04.3 or something else.
What should I do now

Comment: `internal compiler error` indeed sounds like a compiler bug.

Comment: "Please submit a full bug report,**
with preprocessed source if appropriate." as instructed

Comment: what does preprocessed source mean.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression in the gcc 4.4.1 compiler. You should update your Ubuntu system to fix it, or using versions superior than 4.4.5. The precise version (12.04) includes a patched version of gcc.

See [this bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43370) for more information.